# Can I Angular 2 application be non single page application?

Tags: angular

My website's front-end is currently based on Jquery and Jquery UI and plain CSS.
No framework is being used currently. 
I will be using Angular 2 for templatisation client-side. Also, I want to use the power of Angular 2 for few heavy pages.
Is it possible that I can have only some pages in angular 2 and rest of the pages remain same? Basically can Angular 2 achieve non-single page application?
If there are 4 pages in a flow. Can I have just page 2 and 4 in Angular 2 and rest of the pages remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, you can start using Angular 2 just for small pieces, while the rest of the website running still on jquery.

All you need to do, is handle the DOM app element, to which you bound your Angular 2 root component.

Keep the old structure of your old web the same, and just create a new .html for your angular 2 aplication, where you will load all required angular scripts.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <h1>Hi Angular 2</h1>    

      <a href="/index.html">Go to non-angular version of site</a>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

and your Angular 2 view:

```
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
```